# How to manage users and roles for S/4HANA from Java?

Tags: java, user-management, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-r3, s4hana

I want to manage Account and Role of SAP S/4HANA Cloud (HEC) by Java code.

My client tries to upgrade to SAP S/4HANA Cloud from R/3. In the previous version of SAP R/3 I could control them using `sapjco3.dll` and `sapjco3.jar`.

I find 2 ways which can manage them:

- SOAP API https://api.sap.com/api/MANAGEBUSINESSUSERIN/overview
- S/4 HANA Cloud SDK  https://developers.sap.com/topics/s4hana-cloud-sdk.html

However I could not get a sample code or an article to manage them on SAP S/4HANA Cloud (HEC).

I want to know how to manage user/role on SAP S/4HANA cloud via my Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the S/4HANA Cloud SDK you might want to have a look at https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/13/deep-dive-17-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-convenient-consumption-of-sap-s4hana-soap-apis/ where it is described how to call a SOAP API. For other ways to communicate with an S/4 system have a look at https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/.

Comment: Thank you sharing me articles. I will check and try it!